# How to hit the api that runs on ubuntu inside virtualbox?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, api, rails-api

i'm facing difficulties to hit the api runs on ubuntu inside virtualbox. virtualbox's ip address is 10.0.2.15 . when im trying to hit this ip, i cant access it.

so help me to hit the rails api, that runs on port 3000

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Probably your **`Linux firewall` is blocking connection**.

So you can do two things make changes in **`IPtables rule to allow connection`**

OR

**`Just turn IPtables service off`**